# How to show error for entering a duplicate record, in a textbox, exsisting in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I am working on a project in .NET (C#), connected with a database. And I am entering values in database through 'text-box' control, for a part of the project. **What I want is to check if the user entering value already exsists in the database and if so, shows error during that time only.**

I have searched for any familiar post here, that could solve my query, but didn't get any.
Thank you.

**my EXACT objective(if not cleared earlier**):-

> when the user enter the value in
>   textbox, automatically an event to
>   check any duplicate records in
>   database should occur. And if found,
>   displays an error message

Comment: What kind of data access layer are you using ado.net, EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to go would be to have a AJAX callback on the `onchange` event of the textbox and then check if the value already exists in your database table.

You could also implement it via a [`ServerSideValidationExtender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650868.aspx) control:

- [ServerSideValidationExtender - ASP.NET Server-Side Validation via AJAX Partial Page PostBack](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/ServerSideValidationExtenderASPNETServerSideValidationAJAXPartialPagePostBack.aspx)

Comment: That I think could serve my objective, But I am not pro with AJAX. Anyways, I'll try, what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AJAX to achieve your objective. call a webservice from client-side to check if the user entering value already exsists in the database. Call this WebService on TextBox's text change event.

Comment: @ Student: your answer also worked for me. But since Martin's answer was more precise, I chosen that as answer. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is:

Before Inserting the new values, query the database to see if a record with the unique value(s) exists. If so show a message to the user, otherwise insert the data.

The query will depend on what fields are unique in your table/database.

Comment: @ Tony: ya, thats a good alternative. But what I want is, when the user enter the value in textbox, automatically an event to check any duplicate records in database should occur. And if found, displays an error message